# Why do wordpress includes and wp_enqueue_scripts need different functions to get their url?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Inside my plugin i have the main plugin file (foo_widget.php)

This are my file locations:

```
wordpressinstallation/wp-content/plugins/foo_widget/foo_widget.php
wordpressinstallation/wp-content/plugins/foo_widget/js/headeranimation.js
wordpressinstallation/wp-content/plugins/foo_widget/foo_widget_class.php
```

Inside foo_widget i want to include a file and second i want to enqueue a script. I know this works:

```
include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'foo_widget_class.php');

wp_enqueue_script('headeranimationJS', plugins_url().'/foo_widget/js/headeranimation.js');
```

Before it works i tried this first:

```
include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'foo_widget_class.php');

wp_enqueue_script(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'js/headeranimation.js');
```

Second i tried this. This also does not work.

```
include(plugins_url().'/foo_widget/foo_widget_class.php');

wp_enqueue_script('headeranimationJS', plugins_url().'/foo_widget/js/headeranimation.js');
```

Why do the include and wp__enqueue_script need different functions for getting their url's?

Comment: The argument of include is path to a file on the server. This is not a URL. The second argument to wp_enqueue_script is a URL. It can be written as plugin_dir_url( `__FILE__` ) . 'js/headeranimation.js'

Comment: also, `wp_enqueue_script` is for loading `.js` files.